# ESP32 shielding inside an inverter

Tags: microcontroller, high-voltage, esp32, wifi, interference

I am thinking about using an ESP32 as a secondary controller for a 12 V DC to 220 V AC inverter to monitor and control overload, low battery, using relays to switch AC output, etc. The inverter will be 2-stage, first 12 V to ~300 V DC at 100 kHz, then DC to AC.

My previous attempts using a Wi-Fi enabled chip like the ESP32 were not that joyful. Everything will have proper isolation like using optocouplers and non-invasive current transformers, but I have no experience in shielding a microcontroller from high voltage interference. I plan on enabling Wi-Fi and the initial stage is high-frequency.

It may work OK, but my main concern is ESP32 creating interference with the actual control circuit like EGS002 because of WiFi for example switching an IGBT when it should be off.

What precautions should I take or should I dump the idea of a smart inverter?

I am planning to build it in 3 sections:

1. 12 V DC to 300 V DC, it will be a salvaged part from a UPS
2. 300 V DC to 230 V AC using an EGS002
3. ESP32 smart control board

I have options to increase physical distance. I have an isolated 20 V DC power supply generated from main battery to drive the EGS002. Can I power the ESP32 from the battery or should I also create an additional isolated supply to drive it?

Comment: Proposed images would help a lot. Your best friends could be flexible ferrite sheet and a good internal conductive screen.

Comment: Added details towards the end, what should I put the sheets around? between mcu and rest? @Andyaka